# Docker can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-volume, mysql-error-2002

I'm a newbie to docker and I'm facing a strange error.

When I run

> `docker run --name some-mysql-5 -d -p 3306:3306  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret  mysql:latest`

followed by

```
docker exec -ti containerid bash 
mysql -uroot -psecret
```

mysql works fine and I can create and populate databases.

But when I try to create a persistent host volume in order to create a shared db like this:

> `docker run --name some-mysql-4 -v C:\Users\User\Desktop\shared_vol_test:/var/lib/mysql/data -d -p 3306:3306  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret  mysql:latest`

followed by

```
docker exec -ti containerid bash 
mysql -uroot -psecret
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I've also tried to run it as an admin but the results are the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Am I creating a shared and persistent volume in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround by creating the volume in this folder `var/lib/mysql` instead of `var/lib/mysql/data`

I've followed the first steps from  [this guide](https://codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com/persistent-data-docker-volumes/)  and it worked out for now.

I say for now because when I tried to execute `mysql -uuser -ppass` the first time didn't work out by dening me the access and after a while it worked with the same credentials and the same command so I could create a db. The db now is present on my host target directory so maybe I've found a solution to my problem. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545919/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq) is mentioned something about the mysql time to be ready, there are still a lot of behaviours that I must understand I guess.

My account name says it all :( :)

Answer (score 0):

`/var/run/mysqld` isn't a shared filesystem between containers. Use the tcp port 3306 for connecting between containers or share the `/var/run/mysqld`